# File transfer - PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, header, download, blob

I am developing a small CMS for clients.

Clients can upload files (working fine) into a mysql database.

I would like to implement a file download so the clients can also download files, similar to a cloud.

This is my issue: I am correctly accessing the database, addressing the file headers, and downloading the file via the browser -

and here's the issue -

The files are saving without any content. Here is some code:

```
//Downloading a file?
if (isset($_POST["mdownload"])){

//Change string to integer
$fid = intval($_POST["mdownload"]);

//Conect to DB
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','****','****','the_DB');

//Make a query
$query = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE id = ".$fid.";";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

//Assign File Row
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

//Piece header info together
$filename = $row[2].".".$row[3];
$thefile = $row[5];
$mime = $row[6];

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($thefile));

ob_clean();
flush();

fread($thefile);
exit;
}
```

I also was needing to reference my file array via the numerical index and couldn't use $row['file'].

I've already lost a day of my life with this :/

Comment: Don't you need to echo out the result of your `fread()` call?

Comment: where would I echo it

Comment: I'd try an `echo(fread($thefile));`

Comment: Thank you andrewski. I was missing the echo.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to have helped.

Comment: You're using `mysqli`, which is great, but you absolutely need to use the [SQL placeholder](http://bobby-tables.com/php) feature by employing `bind_param` on your values to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/)